# How to localize my wtform?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, wtforms, python-babel

I have a form that I want to localize from English to many languages. I can do it either with gettext or the datastore and I've chosen gettext for performance but I could also use the datastore to store my translations. The actual translations are stored in .po files that I compile with poedit to .mo localization files. The view of the form is:
[image]

The validations also localize but that category should be required is not working:
[image]

And the backend code is

```
class MyTextInput(TextInput):

    def __init__(self, error_class=u'has_errors'):
        super(MyTextInput, self).__init__()
        self.error_class = error_class

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        if field.errors:
            c = kwargs.pop('class', '') or kwargs.pop('class_', '')
            kwargs['class'] = u'%s %s' % (self.error_class, c)
        return super(MyTextInput, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)


class MyPasswordInput(PasswordInput):

    def __init__(self, error_class=u'has_errors'):
        super(MyPasswordInput, self).__init__()
        self.error_class = error_class

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        if field.errors:
            c = kwargs.pop('class', '') or kwargs.pop('class_', '')
            kwargs['class'] = u'%s %s' % (self.error_class, c)
        return super(MyPasswordInput, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)


class RequiredIf(Required):

    # a validator which makes a field required if
    # another field is set and has a truthy value

    def __init__(
        self,
        other_field_name,
        *args,
        **kwargs
        ):

        self.other_field_name = other_field_name
        super(RequiredIf, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        other_field = form._fields.get(self.other_field_name)
        if other_field is None:
            raise Exception('no field named "%s" in form'
                            % self.other_field_name)
        if other_field.data:
            logging.info('other_field.data 2' + str(other_field.data))
            super(RequiredIf, self).__call__(form, field)


class MyTextArea(TextArea):

    def __init__(self, error_class=u'has_errors'):
        super(MyTextArea, self).__init__()
        self.error_class = error_class

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        if field.errors:
            c = kwargs.pop('class', '') or kwargs.pop('class_', '')
            kwargs['class'] = u'%s %s' % (self.error_class, c)
        return super(MyTextArea, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)


from wtforms.widgets import html_params


class SelectWithDisable(object):

    """
    Renders a select field.

    If `multiple` is True, then the `size` property should be specified on
    rendering to make the field useful.

    The field must provide an `iter_choices()` method which the widget will
    call on rendering; this method must yield tuples of
    `(value, label, selected, disabled)`.
    """

    def __init__(self, multiple=False):
        self.multiple = multiple

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('id', field.id)
        if self.multiple:
            kwargs['multiple'] = 'multiple'
        html = [u'<select %s>' % html_params(name=field.name, **kwargs)]
        for (val, label, selected, disabled) in field.iter_choices():
            html.append(self.render_option(val, label, selected,
                        disabled))
        html.append(u'</select>')
        return HTMLString(u''.join(html))

    @classmethod
    def render_option(
        cls,
        value,
        label,
        selected,
        disabled,
        ):
        options = {'value': value}
        if selected:
            options['selected'] = u'selected'
        if disabled:
            options['disabled'] = u'disabled'
        return HTMLString(u'<option %s>%s</option>'
                          % (html_params(**options),
                          escape(unicode(label))))


class SelectFieldWithDisable(SelectField):

    widget = SelectWithDisable()

    def iter_choices(self):
        for (value, label, selected, disabled) in self.choices:
            yield (value, label, selected, disabled, self.coerce(value)
                   == self.data)


from wtforms.widgets import html_params, HTMLString
from cgi import escape


class MyOption(object):

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        options = dict(kwargs, value=field._value())
        if field.checked:
            options['selected'] = True

        label = field.label.text
        render_params = (html_params(**options), escape(unicode(label)))
        return HTMLString(u'<option %s>%s</option>' % render_params)


class AdForm(Form):

    my_choices = [
        ('1', _('All categories')),
        ('disabled', _('VEHICLES')),
        ('2', _('Cars')),
        ('3', _('Motorcycles')),
        ('4', _('Accessories & Parts')),
        ('disabled', _('PROPERTIES')),
        ('7', _('Apartments')),
        ('8', _('Houses')),
        ('9', _('Commercial properties')),
        ('10', _('Land')),
        ('disabled', _('ELECTRONICS')),
        ('12', _('Mobile phones & Gadgets')),
        ('13', _('TV/Audio/Video/Cameras')),
        ('14', _('Computers')),
        ('disabled', _('HOME & PERSONAL ITEMS')),
        ('16', _('Home & Garden')),
        ('17', _('Clothes/Watches/Accessories')),
        ('18', _('For Children')),
        ('disabled', _('LEISURE/SPORTS/HOBBIES')),
        ('20', _('Sports & Outdoors')),
        ('21', _('Hobby & Collectables')),
        ('22', _('Music/Movies/Books')),
        ('23', _('Pets')),
        ('20', _('BUSINESS TO BUSINESS')),
        ('24', _('Hobby & Collectables')),
        ('25', _('Professional/Office equipment')),
        ('26', _('Business for sale')),
        ('disabled', _('JOBS & SERVICES')),
        ('28', _('Jobs')),
        ('29', _('Services')),
        ('30', _('Events & Catering')),
        ('31', _('Others')),
        ]
    nouser = HiddenField(_('No user')) #dummy variable to know whether user is logged in
    name = TextField(_('name'),
                     [validators.Required(message=_('Name is required'
                     ))], widget=MyTextInput())
    title = TextField(_('Subject'),
                      [validators.Required(message=_('Subject is required'
                      ))], widget=MyTextInput())
    text = TextAreaField(_('Text'),
                         [validators.Required(message=_('Text is required'
                         ))], widget=MyTextArea())
    phonenumber = TextField(_('phone'), [validators.Optional()])
    phoneview = BooleanField(_('Display phone number on site'))
    price = TextField(_('Price'), [validators.Regexp('^[0-9]+$',
                      message=_('This is not an integer number, please see the example and try again'
                      )), validators.Optional()], widget=MyTextInput())
    password = PasswordField(_('password'),
                             validators=[RequiredIf('nouser',
                             message=_('Password is required'))],
                             widget=MyPasswordInput())
    email = TextField(_('Email'),
                      [validators.Required(message=_('Email is required'
                      )),
                      validators.Email(message=_('Your email is invalid'
                      ))], widget=MyTextInput())
    category = SelectField(choices=my_choices, option_widget=MyOption())

    def validate_name(form, field):
        if len(field.data) > 50:
            raise ValidationError(_('Name must be less than 50 characters'
                                  ))

    def validate_email(form, field):
        if len(field.data) > 60:
            raise ValidationError(_('Email must be less than 60 characters'
                                  ))

    def validate_price(form, field):
        if len(field.data) > 8:
            raise ValidationError(_('Price must be less than 9 integers'
                                  ))
```

The relevant template code is:

```
<div class="labelform">
    <label>
{% trans %}Category{% endtrans %}:
</label>
  </div></td><td>
  <div class="adinput">

   <select name="{{ form.category.name }}">
   {% for option in form.category %}
       {% if option.data == 'disabled' %}
           {{ option(disabled=True) }}
       {% else %}
           {{ option }}
       {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   </select>

    <div id="err_category" style="display: none; color: red; font-weight: bold;">
      <span class="error" id="err_msg_category"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </td></tr><tr><td>
    <div class="labelform"></div></td><td>
    <div class="adinput">
        <label for="private_ad" id='lprivate_ad'>
        <input id="private_ad" name="company_ad" value="0" checked="checked" type="radio" />
{% trans %}Private{% endtrans %}    
        </label>
    <label for="company_ad" id='lcompany_ad'>
        <input id="company_ad" name="company_ad" value="1" type="radio" />      
{% trans %}Company{% endtrans %}
    </label>
    </div>
    </td></tr><tr><td valign="top">
    {{ form.name.label }}:</td><td>
  <div class="adinput">
{% if user or current_user %} 
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ current_user.name }}{% if not current_user %}{{ user.nickname() }}{% endif %}" size="35" maxlength="50" readonly/>
  {% else %}
    {{ form.name|safe }}
{% endif %}
{% if form.name.errors %} <div class="red">
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.name.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  </td></tr><tr><td valign="top">
{{ form.email.label }}:</td><td>
  <div class="adinput">
{% if user.email or current_user.email %} 
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="{{ current_user.email }}{% if not current_user %}{{ user.email() }}{% endif %}" size="35" maxlength="60" readonly /> 
  {% else %}
    {{ form.email|safe }}
{% endif %}{% if form.email.errors %} <div class="maintext">
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.email.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  </td></tr><tr><td valign="top">{% if not user and not current_user %}
{{ form.password.label }}:
      </td><td>  <div class="adinput">{{ form.password|safe }}{% trans %}Choose a password{% endtrans %}</div>{% if form.password.errors %} <div class="maintext">
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.password.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div>
    {% endif %}{% endif %}

  </td></tr><tr><td valign="top">
    {{ form.phonenumber.label }}:
  </td><td valign="top">
  <div class="adinput">
    {{ form.phonenumber(size="17", maxlength="14")|safe }}{% trans %}Use areacode{% endtrans %}<br>
    {{ form.phoneview|safe }}
    <label for="phone_hidden">{% trans %}View on site{% endtrans %}</label><br />
    {{mareacode}}.
    <div id="err_phone" style="display: none;">
      <span class="warning" id="err_msg_phone"></span>
    </div>
  </div></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">
    <div class="labelform">
 {% filter capitalize %}{% trans %}content type{% endtrans %}{% endfilter %}:</div></td><td>
    <div class="adinput" id="dtype">
    <label style="cursor:pointer;" for="type_s" id="ltype_s">
        <input type="radio" name="type" id="type_s" value="s" checked="checked"  />
 {% trans %}For sale{% endtrans %}
    </label>
      <label style="cursor:pointer;" for="type_k" id="ltype_k">
        <input type="radio" name="type" id="type_w" value="w" />{% trans %}Wanted{% endtrans %}
    </label>
            <div id="warn_type" style="display: none;">
                <span class="warning" id="err_msg_type"></span>
            </div>
      </div>
</td></tr>



<!--
<tr>
<th style="display: table-cell;">Reg. Year:</th>
<td class="param_cell_regdate" style="display: table-cell;">
<select id="regdate" name="regdate">
<div id="err_regdate" style="display: none">
<div class="warning" style="display:none; clear:both; float:none; white-space:nowrap"> </div>
</td>
</tr>
-->


<tr><td valign="top">
{{ form.title.label }}:
  </td><td>
{{ form.title(size='47', maxlength='50', placeholder=_('Please use a descriptive title'))}}{% if form.title.errors %}
        <div class="maintext"> <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.title.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div>
    {% endif %}
    <br/>
    </td></tr><tr><td valign="top">
{{ form.text.label }}:
  </td><td colspan="2">
  <div class="adinput">
   {{form.text(cols="45", rows="10", placeholder=_('Please describe the product or service in a few simple sentences'))|safe}}
{% if form.text.errors %} <div class="maintext">
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.text.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul></div>
    {% endif %}
  </div></td></tr><tr><td>
{{ form.price.label }}:
      </td><td>
      <div class="adinput" id="dprice" style="display: block;">{% if host == "www.montao.com.br" %}R${% else %}
</label><select name="currency" class="currencySelect">
<option value="EUR" >Euros</option>
<option value="AUD">{% trans %}Australian{% endtrans %} Dollars</option>
<option value="BRL" {% if logo == "Montao.com.br" %}selected{% endif %}>{% trans %}Brazilian{% endtrans %} Real</option>
<option value="GBP">{% trans %}British{% endtrans %} Pounds</option>
<option value="CAD">{% trans %}Canadian{% endtrans %} Dollars</option>
<option value="CZK">{% trans %}Czech{% endtrans %} Koruny</option>
<option value="DKK">{% trans %}Danish{% endtrans %} Kroner</option>
<option value="HKD">{% trans %}Hong Kong{% endtrans %} Dollars</option>
<option value="HUF">{% trans %}Hungarian{% endtrans %} Forints</option>
<option value="INR">{% trans %}Indian{% endtrans %} Rupee</option>
<option value="ILS">{% trans %}Israeli{% endtrans %} New Shekels</option>
<option value="JPY">{% trans %}Japanese{% endtrans %} Yen</option>
<option value="MXN">{% trans %}Mexican{% endtrans %} Pesos</option>
<option value="NZD">{% trans %}New Zealand{% endtrans %} Dollars</option>
<option value="NOK">{% trans %}Norwegian{% endtrans %} Kroner</option>
<option value="PHP">{% trans %}Philippine{% endtrans %} Pesos</option>
<option value="PLN">{% trans %}Polish{% endtrans %} Zlotych</option>
<option value="SGD">{% trans %}Singapore{% endtrans %} Dollars</option>
<option value="SEK">{% trans %}Swedish{% endtrans %} Kronor</option>
<option value="CHF">{% trans %}Swiss{% endtrans %} Francs</option>
<option value="TWD">{% trans %}Taiwan{% endtrans %} New Dollars</option>
<option value="THB">{% trans %}Thai{% endtrans %} Baht</option>
<option value="USD">U.S. Dollars</option>
</select>{% endif %}{{ form.price|safe }}{% if logo == "Montao.com.br" %},{% else %}.{% endif %}00 ({% trans %}Optional - do not include period, comma or cents{% endtrans %})
{% if form.price.errors %}
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.price.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
  </td></tr><tr><td>
<div class="labelform">
    <label>{% trans %}Post a photo{% endtrans %}</label>
  </div></td><td>
  <div class="adinput">
    <input type="file" multiple="true" name="file[]" size="35" id="file" />({% filter capitalize %}{% trans %}optional{% endtrans %}{% endfilter %}. {% trans %}Use CTRL on your keyboard to select multiple images.{% endtrans %}) {{resize}}
  </div>
  </td></tr><tr><td></td><td><div class="labelform"></div><div class="adinput">
<!--
{% if not isHuman %} 
{% trans %}You missed the anti-spam test! No problem, please try again:{% endtrans %}
{% endif %}
{{capture|safe}}
-->
<input type="submit" name="validate" value='{% trans %}Continue{% endtrans %}' /></div></td></tr></table></form>
```

The way I receive form input is with HTTP POST:

```
        form = AdForm(self.request.params)
        if form.validate():
            ad.title = form.title.data
            ad.name = form.name.data
            ad.email = form.email.data
            ad.phoneview = form.phoneview.data
            try:
                if form.phonenumber.data:
                    ad.phonenumber = form.phonenumber.data
            except:# to do: change to finally
                pass

            ad.text = form.text.data
            ad.set_password(form.password.data)
            ad.price = form.price.data.replace(' ', '').replace(',00',
                    '').replace('.00', '')
            try:
                if form.price.data:
                    ad.integer_price = form.price.data.replace(' ', ''
                            ).replace(',00', '').replace('.00', '')
            except:
                pass
            ad.url = self.request.host
            ad.place = self.request.get('place')
            ad.postaladress = self.request.get('place')
            ad.put()
        else:
            logging.info('form did not validate')
            self.render_jinja('insert_jinja',
                              facebook_app_id=facebookconf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                              form=form,
                              form_url=blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_form'
                              ))
            return
        if self.request.get('currency'):
            ad.currency = self.request.get('currency')
        if self.request.get('cg'):
            ad.category = self.request.get('cg')  # form.cg.data
        if self.request.get('company_ad') == '1':
            ad.company_ad = True
        ad.put()

        if self.request.host.find('montao') > 0 \
            or self.request.host.find('localhost') > 0:
            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'market',
                                'market_ad_preview.html')
            ad.url = self.request.host

        for upload in self.get_uploads():
            try:
                img = Image(reference=ad)
                img.primary_image = upload.key()
                img.put()
                ad.put()
            except: # to do: change to finally
                pass
        ad.put()
        msg = _('Added %s.') % str(self.request.get('title'))
        message = mail.EmailMessage(sender=self.current_email,
                                    subject=(ad.title if ad.title else ''
                                    ))
        if self.request.host != 'www.montao.com.br':
            message.body = 'Dear ' + ad.name \
                + '\nThank you for registering with ' \
                + self.request.host \
                + '! To edit your ad, click edit from the menu. ' \
                + self.request.host + '/vi/' + str(ad.key().id()) \
                + '''.html
We invite you to visit our home page where you can find latest information on new business announcements from us. From there you can also upload and download videos, music and images.
If you like, you can also add us on Facebook: apps.facebook.com/koolbusiness'''
            message.to = ad.email
            message.send()
        self.redirect('/vi/%d.html' % (ad.key().id(), ))
```

Why don't my categories translate? What's the best way to handle my categories when the option also should be able to get disabled and in those cases get a grey background? Can you see more ways to move rendering from hardcoded HTML and template code to wtforms?

Thanks in advance for any answer or comment

Comment: You must use some kind of [Lazy gettext](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/speaklater) in choices definitions.